# Join Query using ActiveRecord in Yii 2.0 Framework

Tags: php, yii2

I am struggling big time with ActiveRecord.

```
$coupons = Coupon::find()
                     ->select(['{{coupon}}.*','({{website}}.`websitename`) AS WebsiteName'])
                     ->leftjoin('website', '`coupon`.`websiteid`=`website`.`websiteid`')
                     ->limit(10)
                     ->all();
```

This is the join query but its only populates the properties/attributes of the class "Coupon" which seems to be by the books. How do I access a column from the other table "Website"?

```
<?php foreach ($coupons as $coupon): ?>
            <li>
                <?= $coupon->WebsiteName?><br>
            </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This one throws an "unknownPropertyType" exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add public property into your *Coupon* class `public $WebsiteName;`

As another option you can access your *WebsiteName* by defining a [relation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#working-with-relational-data) in your *Coupon* model:

```
public function getWebsite()
{
    $this->hasOne(Website::classname(), ['websiteid' => 'websiteid']);
}
```

And then change your query:

```
$coupons = Coupon::find()->with('website')->limit(10)->all();
```

Then to access property:

```
<?php foreach ($coupons as $coupon): ?>
    <li>
        <?= $coupon->website->WebsiteName?><br>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I already have a separate model for Website which contains a property $WebsiteName. Please let me know if what you are suggesting is a good practice.

Comment: The way you do it, it will help you. Another way is access this property via [relations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#working-with-relational-data)

Comment: Adding a new public property works. Thanks. Can you please point me to better resources for ActiveRecord? The Yii documentation is not good enough.

Comment: You're welcome. I mainly use the documentation, so, unfortunately, cannot suggest you anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Use `print_r($coupon)` to see structire of your`s model. To get name, you must  must call something like: `$coupon->website->Name`

But I recomend you use links hasOne / hasMany.
Read detail [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#hasOne%28%29-detail).